# Undo local changes that exist in a shelveset?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-power-tools

## Problem

Often times, while a team is repairing one part of the code base, we have to have a shelveset of theirs locally so that we can continue working. However, in the process of working I need to shelve my changes for a code review for example. This isn't too much of a problem because I can get their shelveset first, exclude those changes, make my changes, and shelve them.

However, when they have checked in their changes there is no good way for me (except by hand) to simply undo their shelveset (the files that exist in that shelveset specifically). At least I haven't found a way, and so that's why I'm asking.

## Research

So based on [the documentation here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f), there are no commands in `tfpt` that would do this. Further, based on [the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), there are no commands in `tf` that would do this either. I drilled into the `Shelvesets` and `Undo` commands as well looking for possible switches.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Premium version of Visual Studio there are a feature to Suspend your work and after Resume it. You can read the documentarion about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx)