# Is it possible to rollback a shelveset in tfs?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I have done some work on my code and shelved it, then I had to apply a patch to the code from a shelveset to get things working properly.  I then had to fix something else in the code and now wish to make a shelveset, but without the patch, so I want to undo the shelveset that I applied.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: If you have a premium version, you should be able to suspend and resume you work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061664/undo-local-changes-that-exist-in-a-shelveset

Comment: @Freesiah: came with VS2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the state you're currently in: No.

If the original shelveset still exists you could "undo pending changes" then reapply the original shelveset.

There is no local history available to you.

Comment: It is what it is. Can't paint the picture any better.

Comment: I ended up making a copy of my code and then undoing all of my changes. Unfortunate that you can 'unshelve' a set, but you can't 'reshelve'. I could understand if modules from the set itself had changed. But if the changes are only to modules that were not originally part of the shelve set, it should be a rather straightforward matter to backout from that code leaving your unaffiliated changes unaffected. Oh well.